# Integral Linear Combinations Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ be in $\mathbb N_1$ such that $(b,c) = 1$ and $a | bc$. Prove that $a = (a,b)*(a,c)$.

This is ungraded homework and was given out for extra practice, but I can't find the proof.

Anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline proof, see if you can provide the reason for every statement and fill in the details.

Let $g=(a,b)$ and $h=(a,c)$.  Then
$$\frac{a}{g}\Big| \frac{b}{g}\,c\ .$$
Therefore
$$\frac{a}{g}\Big|\ c$$
and so $a\mid gc$.  By a similar process we get $a\mid gh$.

On the other hand $g\mid a$ and $h\mid a$ and $(g,h)=1$, so $gh\mid a$.  Therefore $a=gh=(a,b)(a,c)$.